# Create a zip archive with Ark and use the method Store?

Tags: zip

How can I create a zip archive using the graphical interface of **Ark** and use "**Store**" instead of "**Deflate**" for compression?

**UPDATE**

Apparently, there are significant differences between the versions regarding the compression methods.

The statement '**screenshot from a freshly installed Ark 22.12.3**' by **@Marcus Müller** prompted me to open Ark on another machine.

**Ark 18.8.3**

[image]
[image]

**Ark 20.12.2**

[image]
[image]

I have also found this sentence now on [Creating Archives and Adding Files](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/ark/ark/ark-create.html).

> Note that using compression methods other than the pre-selected defaults may limit compatibility with file archivers. For example, opening zip archives with compression methods other than “Deflate” requires newer archiving software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right there, when you click on "Compression", then select "Store" under "Method".

[image: Ark screenshot]

<sup>screenshot from a freshly installed Ark 22.12.3</sup>

After you add a file, you can inspect your archive with `file`:

```bash
$> file a.zip
a.zip: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract, compression method=store
```

Comment: Sometimes it's the simplest things, like versions :-)

Comment: Glad it helped! By the way, I assume this is for exchange of files that already are compressed with other operating systems that do not come with Unix-typical .tar or cpio or similar tooling, right? If you need just a nice archive that compresses faster than your SSD can write, try tar.zst, in low compression level.

Comment: Yes, I had to modify the file. I think it was originally created with WinRAR on Windows. It was about a bootanimation.zip for Android that somehow requires 'store' instead of 'deflate' in order for the boot animation to work.